# AS3/Flex Override function in imported swf

Tags: apache-flex, import, flash, overriding, actionscript-3

I'm using a flex component that use a  to load a .swf file.

The loaded .swf
- is passed to me as is and I can't edit
- it has some as3 functions in it

Is it possible in the "parent" application (the one with ) to override functions included in the "child" swf (the imported one)?
And if it's possible, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand what you're asking.

It sounds to me like you're loading a SWF at runtime, and want to extend / override methods in that SWF at runtime.

As far as I know there is no way to do that.  You'll have to extend the SWF code in the SWF at compile time.  Without the code I Do not believe it is possible.  If you can get the source code, or get the code as a SWC then you can override and extend the code easily.

IF you share some source code, it may help solidify your request.